# What Framework to Use

Tags: frameworks, file-io, node.js

I am working on an application in Node.js and because this project is for learning more than anything else right now I decided to go with a framework on it.  So I looked at Node's wiki page on GitHub that lists some frameworks and I must say it has driven me dizzy.

My application will have no actual front-end.  It is only to handle any interaction with the file server to write, zip, read, etc. files.  Is there a framework with special methods for working with a file system?  I know Node already has a lot built in.

Comment: Can you get away with standard commandline linux apps? zip, unzip, gzip, tar, etc via the built-in child_process module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [search](http://search.npmjs.org/#/zipfile) [the NPM registry](http://search.npmjs.org/). It has a lot of good packages. I found these packages to help you with zip files for example:

- https://github.com/kriskowal/zip
- https://github.com/springmeyer/node-zipfile

The NPM registry is really amazing :)

Comment: The problem is that most of the modules don't have websites and the registry doesn't offer any descriptions for the modules.

Comment: these modules do have websites. But you are right some people forget to add proper description to package.json. But a lot of the times doing a google search for the package will help you find the github site. If the github site has any documentation(tests/examples) then I am going to try the package....